# WPF how to access sibling from custom UserControl code

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, siblings

If there is a WPF `Window` or `UserControl0` which contains two other controls:

`UserControl1` - custom user control with separate xaml and code-behind

`UserControl2` - custom user control with separate xaml and code-behind

How to access / reference `UserControl1` from `UserControl2` code-behind?
I know that I can get parent from code-behind by using `this.Parent` (inherited from `FrameworkElement.Parent`), and also can obtain parent window by `Window.GetWindow(this)`. But what about referencing this sibling control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's bad practice, still easily doable. Add a property of type Usercontrol2 to UserControl1 and a property of type Usercontrol1 to UserControl2. In the Window or UserControl0 constructor set these properties:

```
UserControl1.UserControl2 = UserControl2;
UserControl2.UserControl1 = UserControl1;
```

Make sure UserControls have names in Window.xaml (names UserControl1 and UserControl2 here are just for exampl)

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, it was wrong and I deleted it. Your answer actually worked for me, thanks. You also mention that this is bad practice. What is then should be good practice?

Comment: Good practice is to use MVVM, use bindings and let models to have links to each other, not controls itself. It allows you to use these controls alone, to test, for example. If controls need to have links to each other, it makes meaningless splitting them to separated controls.

Comment: Also, in some cases this work can be done in Window's xaml, using styles and triggers.

Comment: I split them because my Control2 is actually a real-time Image (SharpDX Direct2D image with it's own rendering logic), whose rendering depends on what is input in Control1. And I don't know how to implement MVVM together with Direct2D, maybe it's just my inexperience.

Comment: I don't know either, but usually I do it by making dependency properties to controls and using them in one of scenarios above.

Answer (score 0):

Give each control a name, more precisely `x:Name`.

Example:

```
<UserControl0 x:Name="control0">
  <StackPanel>
    <UserControl1 x:Name="control1"/>
    <UserControl2 x:Name="control2"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl0>
```

From code-behind in UserControl0.cs, you can access `control1` and `control2`.

If you want UserControl2 to access UserControl1 in this case, you can create an instance variable in the window where UserControl0 is defined.

```
public static MainWindow Instance;
public MainWindow () {
    Instance = this;
```

Access like:

```
App.MainWindow.Instance.control1
```

Comment: Well, in your example I can access `control1` and `control2` names only from `UserControl0` code-behind. But I actually need to access `control1` from `UserControl2` code-behind (which is a separate code and it knows nothing about `control1` code and `UserControl0` code, although it could obtain parent by the methods I mentioned). My problem is there is some logic in `UserControl2` code-behind which depends on some changing `UserControl1` properties.

Comment: I believe I have updated my answer to describe what you have in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in UserControl1's code behind:

```
    public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        //get parent item
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

        //we've reached the end of the tree
        if (parentObject == null) return null;

        //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
        else
            return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        StackPanel container = FindParent<StackPanel>(this);
        UserControl user_control2 = container.Children[1] as UserControl;
    }
```